# Is there a way to use node modules when running a live server

Tags: node-modules, npm-live-server, atom-liveserver

I have a simple website with multiple pages and I need to use the mysql module for something in it.

Whenever I try to run the live-server,and enter the my document that requires the module, I'll get an error message in the console saying that require is not defined, but if I load that specific document with node it works.

So basically is there a way to get the same result while still running my page as a live server?

I tried looking at the live-server documentation in npm, and following the "node" instructions in the docs, but when I load the js file with node it'll kindly tell me that live-server is not an installed module

Comment: Why don't you use `nodemon` it's an alternate to live server, fast, easy to setup and it works for databases too

Comment: I'm looking into it now